# Multithread calculation over sorted combinations of alphabet in C

Tags: c, performance, combinations

I want to multi-thread a "brute-force" algorithm.

I have a function `bool check(const char *s, size_t n)` that checks if the string `s` of size `n` is the password or not.

This function is called for all string combinations that are possible with my alphabet (about 90 chars in the alphabet).

I was able to do it in one thread, but now I want to multi-thread it. **I also want my threads to each have almost the same amount of work** I do not want one thread to have to test 1B combinations and the other one only 1k).

I thought of splitting the load in "batches" of combinations. Each batch would have a `start` index and a `stop` index so the thread having the batch has to test all the combinations between `start` and `stop`.

What I call the index of a combination is its lexicographical index, for example with alphabet [A, B, C]:

```
index combination
1        A 
2        B
3        C
4        AA
5        AB
6        AC
7        BA
8        BB
...      ...
```

For example, a thread who would be assigned the batch with `start=4`and `stop=7` would test combinations `AA, AB, AC, BA`.

How can I easily generate the combinations for a batch in a thread? The priority is for it to be fast, since the whole point of the program is brute forcing.

Is there another fast way to split the work between threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lexicographical order would be fine to work with if you already had all of your strings in a list, but it is not easy at all to work with if you want to be generating the strings.  So, I would forget it as an idea.

Instead, what you could do is start 90 threads, give each thread a starting letter to work with, and have each thread consider words consisting of the first letter that it was given, plus all combinations of the remaining letters.

Comment: I might suggest dividing the starting characters amongst a number of threads equal to however many logical cores you have, in order to avoid any context-switching overhead

Comment: @Nic actually, the way I understand how modern pipelined CPUs work, there can be significant benefits in having way more threads than cores.  But let's not argue about this here, because it is a different subject, suitable for a different question and answer.

Comment: Looks like there is a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24716319/4126177 :)