# Best batch distribution algorithm for parallelization

Tags: c#, algorithm, parallel-processing

I'm working with a pre-structured framework which expects to receive bunch of tasks then it attempts to distribute these tasks among the available cores, my territory is limited to create those tasks and pass them to that framework.

Challenge: I'm looking for an algorithm to be able to juggle between number of tasks and number of requests need which to be processed.

for example, I don't want to have more than 1 task if incoming requests are between 20-50, because for large number of requests the process might become sluggish if too many cores/processes are involved.

I tested for number of 5000 requests and 64 task which resulted to two time more than the time it spent for single task to get completed, so i prefer more smart way for that task generation process.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3126154/1997232). If tasks are CPU bound there is no point in creating more than the number of CPU cores I guess.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes but still need an algorithm to create those tasks according to the number of cores and requests.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` or `Parallel.ForEachAsync` maybe? With a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` option.

Comment: ...Or you can use `Channels`: you put requests into Writer, read and process request from Reader.  You can manually create /  tasks to process, i.e. change degree of parallelism in the process.