Benefit of running of 8 threads when you have 4 CPU cores
In C++ a standard library function is std::hardware_concurrency which as stated in the documentation:

Returns the number of hardware thread contexts.
Note that this does not need to match the actual number of processors
or cores available in the system: A system can support multiple
threads per processing unit, or restrict the access to its resources
to the program.

My CPU has 4 cores but hardware_concurrency returns 8, I think due to Intel Hyperthreading. I can't understand the benefit of running 8 threads when you have only 4 CPU cores. According to another answer her on SE:

Two threads are concurrent with each other when both have been started
but neither one of them has finished.
Two threads are running in parallel with each other when each of them
is actively using cycles on a different CPU core during the same
interval of time.

So let's just say you spawn 8 threads and you have 4 CPU cores. Your 8 threads might be running concurrently, but not in parallel? The number 8 is the number of HARDWARE THREADS, so it's not even the OS scheduler that says:

Right, we have 8 threads but we only have 4 CPU cores, so when running
these 8 threads, so we'll switch the running of threads that use
single CPU core cycles.

Because there are actually 8 HARDWARE threads, the OS can just assume that there are 8 cores. And so the switching is done entirely in hardware, right? Which is more efficient.
However, even with this hyperthreading technology, the OS hands off 8 jobs to the CPU, the hardware is responsible for scheduling the CPU cycles for each thread, the end result is that what's actually running in PARALLEL is only 4 things. And I should add, in my opinion somewhat less efficiently because the hardware is actually doing the scheduling from one job to the other among 8 different threads competing for the resources of 4 CPU cores.
Anecdotally, in reality, with 4 CPU cores, I haven't realised any performance increase above 3 or 4, so I think my theory is correct. Also, I think from 3 to 4 the increase might have only been marginal, and that's possibly because one thread is waiting for others to join (but that's another issue and possibly question).
If all the above is correct, then the only advantage of running more threads than CPU cores, even with something like Hyperthreading, is a sort of "interleaving" of tasks on the same CPU resources so that it appears things are running in parallel but each thing is actually running slower.
I have no idea how CPUs work so could someone please explain if I am wrong.

Sort of.  Hyperthreading does, in fact, do interleaving.  Your CPU instructions are subdivided into microinstructions, and a CPU can process other microinstructions while it's waiting on something else.  In general, threads tend to be lightweight, and there is no real disadvantage to running 20 threads even if you only have 4 CPUs.  The operating systems are very, very good at scheduling so the work gets completed quickly.

Also remember that your 4 threads don't "own" those 4 CPUs.  There are thousands of threads running in your computer, so your threads are just part of a rather large pool of threads waiting for service.

And so the switching is done entirely in hardware, right? Assuming you're on a modern x86, it's not even switching, it's fine-grained SMT.  Instructions from both logical cores are in flight at the same time.  They alternate every cycle in the front-end (unless one is stalled, e.g. on a cache miss or branch mispredict), but out-of-order exec in the back-end can find work to do from either thread.  https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/ has a good intro to CPU architecture.  (Intel's brand-name for their SMT is Hyperthreading.)

@TimRoberts I thought switches between threads was expensive, is that what they refer to as a context switch? Also I just looked at my Task Manager, Windows sees 8 logical cores, even though there are 4 CPUs.

SMT can be good for overall throughput if your threads bottleneck on instruction latency like naive sum += arr[i] for floating-point without -ffast-math, but it can hurt overall throughput by creating more cache misses as two threads compete for the same L1d / L2 cache, especially in well-tuned code that can use most of a physical core's execution resources from a single thread.

@PeterCordes  "Instructions from both logical cores are in flight at the same time." So they actually do run at the same time? I actually mean at the same time in parallel. Then why haven't I seen any performance difference between 4 and 8 threads.?

@Zebrafish: Yes, context-switches typically result in quite a lot of cache misses in the newly-resumed thread until caches repopulate with whatever they were working on.  For number-crunching type of work, you don't want the machine running many more tasks than it has logical cores.  But OSes schedule tasks with a coarse enough timer (like 100 Hz or 1000 Hz) that there are still lots of clock cycles of useful work between switches, especially on modern CPUs at like 4GHz instead of 100 MHz

Yes, they run at the same time.  Theoretical max throughput isn't any higher with both logical cores active, but it's better at hiding stalls.  (Conversely, competing for cache and TLB entries etc. can cause more stalls, and competing for out-of-order exec resources limits the ability to find parallelism in each thread.)  Speedups from running 2 threads per physical core vs. 1 vary wildly depending on workload, ranging from negative for HPC code like matmuls, to like +15% for x265 -preset slow on my i76700k Skylake, to +100% theoretical max for code with bad bottlenecks on e.g. FP latency.

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3126154/62576

See also https://agner.org/optimize/ for a deep dive on CPU microarchitecture and which resources are competitively shared vs. statically partitioned (each logical core gets half) vs. replicated, in various designs.  And his comments on when HT won't give any speedup.

If you have a specific question about why your workload doesn't benefit from more threads, we need details like an [mcve].  Some algorithms don't scale linearly with number of threads, or at least have some overhead and contention for getting partial results communicated and synchronized between threads.

@PeterCordes I'm so confused. Some CPUs have 4 cores that present themselves at the software level as 8 different cores. As a programmer when I decide how many threads I want my program/algorithm to run on why should I try second guess what the OS has reported as being the number of cores that are available to work with? The point of SMT/Hyperthreading is for the CPU to act AS IF it has a certain number of cores to the user. I should use that, right?

Many software APIs for reporting hardware concurrency predate SMT, so often don't easily provide number of physical cores, only number of logical cores.  For a lot of programs, running one thread per logical core isn't worse (and rarely much worse) than 1 thread per physical core, so it's not real problem that those APIs report logical cores.  If you want to make more of an effort to tune a specific program for some specific hardware or classes of hardware (e.g. Intel Ice Lake or AMD Zen family), you might do some experiments and find what runs best.

that present themselves at the software level as 8 different cores. - Not just "at a software level".  An ancient or simplistic OS that wasn't aware of hyperthreading would just see it as an 8-core machine.  Hyperthreading / SMT awareness means avoiding scheduling threads onto sibling logical cores when there are free physical cores, which they do by detecting which logical cores share a physical core via cpuid on x86.

@PeterCordes OK, well all this is extremely complicated and hard to get to the bottom of, so I'm just going with one main thread, one IO thread for disk storage and sockets, and then worker threads which will be num_PHYSICAL_cores - 1 (if I can even find out what that is in a cross-platform way.

Why minus 1?  Does the main thread use 100% CPU normally?  I/O and GUI event processing (if that's what your main thread does) are perfectly suited to sharing a physical core with number crunching work. On a non-SMT CPU, you might want the -1 so there's always an unused core for better responsiveness, if that's at all a problem, although of course that will cost throughput for your workers.

But yeah other than that, sounds like a very reasonable plan for most workloads.

@PeterCordes "Why minus 1?" - I have no clue, this is way too complicated. Don't worry, nothing ten years of studying the topic won't fix.

It depends a lot what you are trying to do. I find that for very heavy computation bound stuff on a 4 core Intel 8 hyperthread machine that optimum performance is obtained with 6/8 hyperthread running the worker code flat out and it is worth staying at that. Adding an additional CPU just generates more heat and can even slow things down. Basically you run as many as you can just short of saturating memory or disk IO bandwidth. Having the option to use less than all those available can be useful.

To understand SMT with an analogy, imagine 2 person on the same desktop having 1 shared phone, 1 PC, 1 screen, 1 keyboard, 1 mouse but some (partitioned) physical space for each, 2 brains, 2 bodies. It becomes trivial that the speed improvement of having 2 person is dependent of the task then (even its implementation). If you have to call 8 friends using your phone then it will not be faster. But if you need to call people with phone numbers stores on different web pages, then one can call them and the other can search the numbers on the PC both using the same shared desktop (i.e. core).

In practice, resource sharing/partitioning (desktop setup) is strongly dependent of the CPU architecture, and applications are composed of a lot of different tasks. Not to mention each task can often be implemented in a way to either benefit from SMT or not (at the expense of a possibly slower execution on CPU not having multiple threads per cores). Thus, in real-world cases, this is often so complex that the best is simply to run a test or even better: let the user choose for you! In fact, users can leverage SMT by running other applications simultaneously (doing very different tasks).

"According to another answer her on SE..." That was my answer. I have deleted it. Looking back, I don't think it actually said what I wanted it to say.

@SolomonSlow You deleted your answer? Why? And how did you find this question so promptly?

I don't like the way I described "parallel" back then. IMO, that word is kind of a slippery fish. Easy to get into arguments about what it really means, and winning or losing the argument won't help anybody's program perform any better. I just don't want to go there right now.

@SolomonSlow Well, OK. But it's in my head now, the distinction between concurrency and parallelism.
